# What age should be a Goy to be spared and how it is determined?

Tags: gentiles, army-military-war, age, parashas-shoftim

> אִם־לֹא תַשְׁלִים עִמָּךְ וְעָשְׂתָה עִמְּךָ מִלְחָמָה וְצַרְתָּ עָלֶיהָּ׃
>   וּנְתָנָהּ ה"א בְּיָדֶךָ וְהִכִּיתָ אֶת־כָּל־זְכוּרָהּ לְפִי־חָרֶב׃
>   רַק הַנָּשִׁים וְהַטַּף וְהַבְּהֵמָה וְכֹל אֲשֶׁר יִהְיֶה בָעִיר כָּל־שְׁלָלָהּ תָּבֹז לָךְ וְאָכַלְתָּ אֶת־שְׁלַל אֹיְבֶיךָ אֲשֶׁר נָתַן יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ לָךְ׃
>
> If it does not surrender to you, but would join battle with you, you shall lay siege to it; and when the LORD your God delivers it into your hand, you shall put all its males to the sword. You may, however, take as your booty the women, the children, the livestock, and everything in the town—all its spoil—and enjoy the use of the spoil of your enemy, which the LORD your God gives you. ([Deut 20.13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.20.13?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0))

Rashi says: "והטף. אַף טַף שֶׁל זְכָרִים, וּמָה אֲנִי מְקַיֵּם "וְהִכִּיתָ אֶת כָל זְכוּרָהּ"? בַּגְּדוֹלִים:" ([See Sifrei Dvorim](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sifrei_Devarim.200.5?lang=bi)).

What age is considered Taf (טף - children) to be spared and how is it determined (assuming we don't know their language and they don't have IDs)?